# OpenCl Error -40

Tags: runtime-error, opencl, gpgpu

I've been coding some openCl programs for a while and now i'm trying to make a simple program that read an image in .pam format and then save it as is.

Now the problem is that when i run it, giving a name to open an image it returns an error -40 when creating the first 2dImage.

Here's the code:

```
#define SEPARATOR "==============================================\n"
/* Copia tutto tranne <imgInfo>.data
 * -Questo vuol dire che l'immagine avrà anche stessa altezza e larghezza */
void copy_img_info(imgInfo* src, imgInfo *dst){
    dst->channels=src->channels;
    dst->data_size=src->data_size;
    dst->depth=src->depth;
    dst->height=src->height;
    dst->maxval=src->maxval;
    dst->width=src->width;
}

cl_event launch_op(cl_command_queue que, cl_kernel k_op, 
        imgInfo info_open, imgInfo info_to_save,
        int _lws, 
        cl_mem src, cl_mem dst,
        cl_int num_events, const cl_event* wait_list){
        cl_int err;
        cl_event evt_kernel;
        size_t lws[]={
            _lws ? _lws : 16, _lws ? _lws : 16
        };
        size_t gws[]={
            round_mul_up(info_open.height, lws[0]), round_mul_up(info_open.width, lws[1])
        };
        err = clSetKernelArg(k_op, 0, sizeof(src),&src);
        ocl_check(err, "Set op k arg 0");
        err = clSetKernelArg(k_op, 1, sizeof(dst),&dst);
        ocl_check(err, "Set op k arg 1");
        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(que, k_op, 2, NULL, gws, lws, num_events, wait_list, &evt_kernel);
        ocl_check(err, "Enqueue kernel op");
        return evt_kernel;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if( argc <2 ){
        printf("Inserire nome del file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int _lws;
    if( argc <3)
        _lws= 0;
    else{
        _lws= atoi(argv[2]);
        printf("Sarà usato %d come local work size\n",_lws);
    }

    imgInfo info_open, info_to_save;

    cl_event evt_fill[2], evt_upload, evt_op, evt_download;
    cl_image_format format = {
        .image_channel_data_type = CL_UNSIGNED_INT16,
        .image_channel_order = CL_RGBA
    };

    cl_int err;

    cl_platform_id p = select_platform();
    cl_device_id d = select_device(p);
    cl_context ctx = create_context(p, d);
    cl_command_queue que = create_queue(ctx, d);
    cl_program prog = create_program("Kernels/image_tr.ocl",NULL , ctx, d);

    if(load_pam(argv[1], &info_open)){
        printf("Errore durante apertura file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    copy_img_info(&info_open, &info_to_save);

/* ALLOCATION OF BUFFERS */
    cl_mem image_to_open = clCreateImage2D(ctx, CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_READ_ONLY , &format, info_open.width, info_open.height,
            info_open.width, NULL, &err );
    ocl_check(err, "Allocate image to open");
    cl_mem image_to_save = clCreateImage2D(ctx, CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , &format, info_to_save.width, info_to_save.height,
            info_to_save.width, NULL, &err );
    ocl_check(err, "Allocate image to save");
/* ALLOCATION OF BUFFERS */ 


/* FILL IMAGES */
    const size_t fill_color[]={0,0,0,0};
    const size_t origin[3]= {0,0,0};
    const size_t region[3]= { info_open.width, info_open.height, 1};
    err = clEnqueueFillImage(que, image_to_open, fill_color , origin, region, 0, NULL, evt_fill);
    ocl_check(err, "Enqueue Fill Buffer to open");
    err = clEnqueueFillImage(que, image_to_save, fill_color , origin, region, 0, NULL, evt_fill + 1);
    ocl_check(err, "Enqueue Fill Buffer to save");
/* FILL IMAGES */

/* UPLOAD IMAGE ON GPU */
    err = clEnqueueWriteImage(que, image_to_open, CL_TRUE, origin, region,
            info_open.width, 0, info_open.data, 1, evt_fill, &evt_upload  );
    ocl_check(err, "Upload image on GPU");
/* UPLOAD IMAGE ON GPU */


/* CREATION OF KERNELS */
    cl_kernel k_op = clCreateKernel(prog, "op", &err );
    ocl_check(err, "Creation of kernel op");
/* CREATION OF KERNELS */

/* LAUNCH CUSTOMS KERNELS */
   const cl_event evt_wait_list [] = {
       evt_fill, evt_upload
   };
   evt_op = launch_op(que, k_op, info_open, info_to_save, _lws, image_to_open, image_to_save, 2, evt_wait_list); 
/* LAUNCH CUSTOMS KERNELS */    
/* DOWNLOAD FROM GPU */
   err = clEnqueueReadImage(que, image_to_save, CL_TRUE, origin, region, info_to_save.width, 0, 
           info_to_save.data, 1, &evt_op, &evt_download);
   ocl_check(err, "Download from device");
/* DOWNLOAD FROM GPU */
/* SAVE PAM FILE */
   if(save_pam("ocl_image_tr.pam",&info_to_save))
       printf("Errore salvataggio file Pam\n");
/* SAVE PAM FILE */
/* BENCHMARKING */
   cl_ulong runtime_fill[2]={
       runtime_ns(*evt_fill), runtime_ns(*(evt_fill+1) )
   };
   cl_ulong runtime_upload= runtime_ns(evt_upload);
   cl_ulong runtime_op = runtime_ns(evt_op);
   cl_ulong runtime_download = runtime_ns(evt_download);

   printf(SEPARATOR);
   printf(" Kernel \t Runtime \t Bandwidth \t GFLOPS\n");
   printf(" Fill_1 \t %gms \t %gGB/s \t %g GFLOPS\n", 1.0e-6*runtime_fill[0],
           (double)(info_open.height*info_open.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_fill[0]),
           (double)(info_open.height*info_open.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_fill[0]));
   printf(" Fill_2 \t %gms \t %gGB/s \t %g GFLOPS\n", 1.0e-6*runtime_fill[1],
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_fill[1]),
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_fill[1]));
   printf(" Upload \t %gms \t %gGB/s \t %g GFLOPS\n", 1.0e-6*runtime_upload,
           (double)(info_open.height*info_open.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_upload),
           (double)(info_open.height*info_open.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_upload));
   printf(" Op \t %gms \t %gGB/s \t %g GFLOPS\n", 1.0e-6*runtime_op,
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_op),
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_op));
   printf(" Download \t %gms \t %gGB/s \t %g GFLOPS\n", 1.0e-6*runtime_download,
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_download),
           (double)(info_to_save.height*info_to_save.width*sizeof(cl_short4))/(runtime_download));
   printf(SEPARATOR);
/* BENCHMARKING */


/* CLEANING... */
    clReleaseEvent(evt_op);
    clReleaseEvent(evt_download);
    clReleaseEvent(*evt_wait_list);
    clReleaseEvent(*(evt_wait_list+1));
    clReleaseEvent(*evt_fill);
    clReleaseEvent(*(evt_fill+1));
    clReleaseMemObject(image_to_open);
    clReleaseMemObject(image_to_save);
    clReleaseDevice(d);
    clReleaseKernel(k_op);
    clReleaseProgram(prog);
    clReleaseContext(ctx);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(que);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the kernel:

```
__kernel void op(image2d_t read_only src, image2d_t write_only dst){
    // Questa mappatura è più efficiente per la GPU
    const sampler_t sampler_ui = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_NONE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST ;
    int row= get_global_id(1);
    int col=get_global_id(0);
    if( row > get_image_height(src) && col > get_image_width(src))
        return;
    uint4 pix= read_imageui(src, sampler_ui ,(int2)(row,col));
    write_imageui(dst, (int2)(row,col), pix);
}
```

The headers i used are been created by my teacher of GPGPU and i can't give it.
There's the error given:

```
Allocate image to open - error -40
```

The message is that I print in allocating the images.
What is going on?

Comment: The error -40 is CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE, but the images are 479x400 or 1280x900

Comment: Is this really a **minimal** example?

Comment: I've forgot, I'm using Opencl 1.1 with Nvidia Cuda 7.5

Comment: @loki Ok, it's not minimal, but it's really simple what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is having the same problem.
I resolved in this way

```
cl_uint numb;
    clGetSupportedImageFormats(ctx, NULL , CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D, 0, NULL, &numb);
    printf("Numb: %u\n", numb);
```

This returns me always Numb: 0

But when i changed the CreateImage2d with CreateImage from Opencl 1.2...
It finally works